# matching full strings in python, what syntax is this?

Tags: python, regex

In one exercise one had to write a function that took a string as input and it would return 'Valid' if the string consisted only of the word 'racecar' one or multiple times, without leading and trailing spaces and a maximum of one space separating the words. Otherwise return 'Not valid'.

I wrote the following function which I think is correct.

```
def is_valid(s):
    match = re.match(r'^racecar(\sracecar)*$', s)
    return 'Valid' if match != None else 'Not valid'
```

In the solution they used a different approach which I had never seen before. What's the name for the following syntax used in the return statement?

```
def is_valid(s):
    l = s.split(' ')
    return ['Not valid', 'Valid'][all(s == 'racecar' for s in l)]
```

Comment: `['Not valid', 'Valid']` is called a list.

Comment: “Needlessly confusing”. `['Not valid', 'Valid']` is a list literal, booleans also work as indexes 0 and 1, and it would be better written as `'Valid' if all(s == 'racecar' for s in l) else 'Not valid'` like you had. (Or even better, just return a boolean like the function’s name implies.)

Comment: Your second version accepts an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`['Not valid', 'Valid']` is a list

`all(s == 'racecar' for s in l)` is `True` if all elements in `l` are `'racecar'`, `False` otherwise. Since `bool` is a subclass of `int` (where `True -> 1, False -> 0`) you can use this expression to index into the two-element list.

```
['Not valid', 'Valid'][all(s == 'racecar' for s in l)]
#  coerced to 0 or 1 --^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# in context where an int is required
```

is therefore equivalent to

```
'Valid' if all(s == 'racecar' for s in l) else 'Not valid'
```

I would, however, not use this in "real" code as it may confuse you or your co-workers when reading it at a later stage. Also, as [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) has pointed out in the comments, this version does accept the empty string as valid. You could fix that by adding a check though:

```
['Not valid', 'Valid'][l and all(s == 'racecar' for s in l)]
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. It's just a bit more obscure code and not actually new syntax.